# File I/O: Reading from one file and writing to another (Java)

Tags: java, file, io

I'm currently working on a lab in my cpe class and we have to create a simple program that scans in strings from a .txt file and prints them to a different .txt file. So far I have the basic program drawn out but my exception keeps getting throw though I have all the necessary files. Can anyone help me debug?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileIO {

public static void main(String args[]) {        
    try {
        File input = new File("input");
        File output = new File("output");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            printer.write(s);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your in/output file doesn't have an extension?

Comment: He already said they're .txt files... so it looks like that's the problem. A bit of advice for any computer you plan to do programming on: set your file browser to always show file extensions.

Comment: Don't forget to close scanner and writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to figure out where it looks for the `"input"` file. When you just specify `"input"` it looks for the file in the **current working directory**. When working with an IDE, this directory may not be what you think it is.

Try the following:

```
System.out.println(new File("input").getAbsolutePath());
```

to see where it looks for the file.

Comment: Thanks!! It turns out my .txt files were in the wrong folder. So it's finding them but now it is not writing over from my input.txt to my output.txt. Output.txt is still empty.

Comment: *That's* because you don't call flush. I suggest you call printer.close() when you're done (which will flush it for you).

Comment: Thanks!! It works now! I closed my scanner but not my printer.

Answer (score 5):

May be you are just forget the `flush()`

```
       try {
            File input = new File("input");
            File output = new File("output");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
            PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                printer.write(s);
            }
            **printer.flush();**
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
        }
```

Comment: He says that he gets an exception.

Comment: @aioobe what is your exception?

Comment: *I* don't have any exceptions, *Mike* (the guy that posted the question) has.

Comment: The exception is thrown because of the file not being found, not because of the printer failing to flush all of its bytes.

Comment: I know this is a super old answer/question but he would indeed need a `printer.close()` call to finish writing to the file

Answer (score 3):

When accessing files with Java I/O, you must include the file's filetype extension (if one exists).

```
    File input = new File("input.txt");
    File output = new File("output.txt");
```

Comment: I had the .txt extensions prior and I would still throw my exception. I am using eclipse and the .txt files are in the src fold along with my .java files.

Comment: I added the extensions back on and moved the files to the correct folder but now every time I run my program, my output.txt gets updated but when I open it up there is still nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by reading the file using **FileInputStream** object and write into another file using **FileOutputStream** object.

Here is the sample code

```
package java_io_examples;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Filetest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\testout.txt");

           int i = 0;
           String s = "";

           while((i=fin.read())!=-1) {

               s = s + String.valueOf((char)i);

           }

           FileOutputStream fout = new 
           FileOutputStream("D:\\newtestout1.txt");
           byte[] b = s.getBytes();

           fout.write(b);
           fout.close();

           System.out.println("Done reading and writing!!");

      } catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Good in principal, but this can be simpler, and can avoid converting into String with default encoding (which is machine environment dependent).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readwrite() throws IOException 
{
    // Reading data from file
    File f1=new File("D:/read.txt");
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(f1);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

    String s = br.readLine();

    // Writing data
    File f2=new File("D:/write.txt");
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f2);
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
    while(s!=null)
    {
        bw.write(s);
        bw.newLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        s=br.readLine();

    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the assumption that the file contains data in any particular format, and using Java 8 try-with-resources:

```
    try (
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\testinfile.dat");
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\testoutfile.dat);
    ) {
        for (int ii = 0; (ii = input.read()) != -1;) output.write(ii);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // who still really uses System.out.println in the real world?
        logger.error("Can't copy test file", e);
    }
```